# eclipse can not start up my tomcat server, how to turn the server on

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

when i try to run the jsp-file using eclipse, eclipse shows me that my tomcat server is turned off although i turned it on from 'startup.bat' file which is located in the bin directory inside the tomcat installation folder.

I encounter the error shown in the image posted below.how to solve it?[image]

Comment: If you need to use tomcat server seperatly form eclipse environment then for eclipse environment define seperate port for tomcat server on eclipse server.config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you configure Tomcat using Runtime configuration in eclipse, then you need NOT to run the tomcat manually. When you execute a server side program such as jsp/servlet, eclipse will first start the associated runtime(Tomcat) and then deploy your jsp/servlet on it.

In your case, as you have manually started the Tomcat, so when eclipse tries to launch the same tomcat, it throws and error saying port already in use.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your sever is already in running state and you are trying to start again.
Any chance you started your server though comand prompt, before trying in eclipse.

If exsist try kiiling the java process of the server in task manager and try again

Answer (score 0):

Let Eclipse handle the Tomcat instance. Run shutdown.bat, then start Tomcat from Eclipse by clicking Windows->Show view->Servers, right click and Start.